# Understanding the chain rule for partial derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Let's suppose to have $L$ function (at leas of class $C^2$) defined on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}$ which should represents the Lagrangian of a system, and $\varphi(\vec{q},\alpha)$ an action of class $C^2$ in both variables. The additional information is that the lagrangian is invariant under the action induced on $\mathcal{TC}$, i.e $$L(\vec{q},\dot{\vec{q}},t) = L\left(\varphi(\vec{q},\alpha),\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial\alpha}(\vec{q},\alpha)\dot{\vec{q}},t\right)$$

How should I compute the following ?

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}L\left(\varphi(\vec{q},\alpha),\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial\alpha}(\vec{q},\alpha)\dot{\vec{q}},t\right)$$

It should be true that it's equal to $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{q}}L\left(\varphi(\vec{q},\alpha),\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial\alpha}(\vec{q},\alpha)\dot{\vec{q}},t\right)\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\varphi(\vec{q},\alpha)+ \cdots$$

Plus similar terms (substituting $\vec{q}$ with $\dot{\vec{q}}$) according to chain rule.

What I don't get is how $\vec{q}$ plays a role here, according to [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) we should have $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\varphi}$.

Is $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\varphi}$ a notation in order to mean $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\vec{q}}?$ Are those different things? Any clarification or help in order to clear this doubt would be appreciated

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think it should have been specified by $L\left(\varphi(\vec{q},\alpha),\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial\alpha}(\vec{q},\alpha)\dot{\vec{q}},t\right)$, but I've edited the question. Downvote seems excessive.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The question is now edited, do you know how to help?

Comment: @YvesDaoust What is missing ? This is the exact setting for Noether Theorem I have in my class notes

Comment: @YvesDaoust This is a more general setting, no need to have an explicit Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$, it sufficient to note that is a Lagrangian $L$ dependant on $\vec{q},\dot{\vec{q}}$ and $t$, is this what you're asking for ?

Comment: What's wrong Yves ?